# Default user agent in Wget

Tags: wget, user-agent

I want to know what default user agent is passed if I use wget from command line without specifying explicit user agent.

I have some code which cahnges output based on user agent .

```
wget http://www.google.com -O test.html
```

Comment: In your code when you would make the if choice print out the user agent to see the value

Answer (score 13):

"wget -d" will show the request made to the server.

```
$ wget -d http://www.google.com -O/dev/null 2>&1 |grep ^User-Agent
User-Agent: Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)
User-Agent: Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)
User-Agent: Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 5):

At your shell prompt, do:

```
> man wget
```

scroll down to `-U agent-string`, which states:

"Wget normally identifies as Wget/version, version being the current version number of Wget".

So do:

```
> wget --version
```

which will give you the version, and thus your user-agent.

Incidently, you may find that some sites block wget, so depending on what you're doing you may need to change this.

Answer (score 1):

On my *Fedora 13* system, it shows `Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)`

Answer (score 0):

Run wget and sniff the communication.

You can also check the web server's log, usually it containts the user agent of the connecting clients.

This is what i got off the latest wget for windows: `Wget/1.11.4`

Answer (score 0):

You could verify this with a network protocol analyzer such as Wireshark.
With Wireshark you can inspect the headers and every other detail of the whole protocol stack involved.

Wireshark is both free and open source: http://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: This is one method for finding the answer, but it isn't in itself an answer to the question.